# Unable to Determine Object Type in F# Function

Tags: compiler-errors, f#, functional-programming

I have the below function in F# and unfortunately in the Seq.filter at the beginning of my fold, w2.Text (in the comparison) is not identified of type Word.  I am not sure how to help the compiler along in this scenario.  The compiler appears to be good on everything else.  This is the first time I've ever run in to this.

```
let CreateWordRelationDB () =
    let db = new AnnotatorModel()
    printfn "%s" "Entered Function and created db v7"
    let tweets = db.Tweets
                |> Seq.cast<Tweet>
                |> Seq.map(fun t -> t.Text)
    let words = db.Words |> Seq.cast<Word> 
    words 
    |> Seq.fold(fun acc w1 ->  
                        let filtacc = acc 
                                      |> Seq.filter(fun w2 -> 
                                                        if(w1.Text = w2.Text) then false else true)
                        filtacc 
                        |> Seq.map(fun w2 -> CreateWordRelation w1 w2 tweets)
                        |> Seq.iter(fun r -> db.WordRelations.Add(r) |> ignore)
                        db.SaveChanges() |> ignore
                        filtacc
                    ) words
```

Comment: This usually only happens if you either have two types that share the fields in use in the expression, or you're using a class rather than record - due to some features in classes such as method overloading, the compiler can't infer such types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add type annotation:

```
|> Seq.filter(fun (w2: Word) -> if(w1.Text = w2.Text) then false else true)
```

Comment: Wow, I'm a goon, I totally forgot I could put parens at that point in the function...

Comment: I tend to put the annotation closest to the point where it's needed, e.g. `(w2:Word).Text`. I'm not sure if this is considered good practice or idiomatic, but it does mean that if the reason for the annotation is removed then the annotation will probably be removed along with it rather than being left behind as clutter.

Comment: Can some simplify: |> Seq.filter(fun (w2: Word) -> w1.Text <> w2.Text)

Answer (score 5):

There is an - arguably - more elegant way than using a type annotation.

The problem here is that type inference for non-F# types (which `Word` essentially is) is less powerful than for F# record/DU types. The compiler can only infer the type for those if the respective value occurs in the code *before* the point where it is used (so its not so much inference but more "type tracking").

You are using `fold` in this manner: `source |> Seq.fold folder state`

So `state`, for which the type still needs to be determined, occurs after the `folder` function, where it is used. You can, however, move it before that point, by using the not-so-well-known `||>` operator.

This operator is defined as `let inline (||>) (a, b) f = f a b` and allows you to curry two separate arguments "onto" a function: `(state, source) ||> Seq.fold folder`

That way, `state` occurs before knowledge of its type is required in `folder`, and the compiler can "remember" the type and use it in the relevant places.

With that, your function call would look like

```
(words, words) // The first is the state, the second the source
||> Seq.fold (fun acc w1 -> ... // long folder function)
```

with no further argument after the `folder` function curried onto `Seq.fold`.

(All credit for this goes to Ross McKinlay who I learned this from.)

Comment: Very neat. This is why I read the F# source code sometimes, to find stuff like this.